# Bootstrap Dropdown is not working in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I include a dropdown button to React from bootstrap Dropdowns, But it is not working and shows as a normal button. Can you give me a solution for this?

```
<div className="dropdown">
    <button className="btn btn-secondary 
                 dropdown-toggle" 
                 type="button" 
                 id="dropdownMenuButton"
                 data-toggle="dropdown"
                 aria-haspopup="true" 
                 aria-expanded="false">
                 Dropdown button
    </button>
            <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

The output is a normal button like this. [image]

Comment: Are you using react-[bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/) ?

Comment: @AjinKabeer I am not using react-bootstrap, I used "npm install bootstrap --save" this only.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`? Are other components being styled correctly by `bootstrap` or is it just `dropdowns` that it doesn't style?

Comment: Yes I am using `create-react-app` and others are styled correctly, only the dropdowns are not working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dropdowns are not working without `popper.js` and `jquery.js`.

So please install `popper.js` and `jquery.js` in your system using `npm install popper.js jquery --save` and don't forget to include it.

**With CDN**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-react-class-m3qfxu?file=index.html

**With NPM**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-react-class-xvsthx?file=index.js

Comment: Can you tell me how to import `popper.js`?

Comment: I give both examples, how to import it

Comment: @PulsaraSandeepa first you need to install `npm i --save bootstrap jquery popper.js` then `import Popper from 'popper.js';` in js file

Answer (score 1):

If someone doesn't want to install other dependencies, they can make it work using react `useState` hook.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function DropCard() {
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);
  const toggleOpen = () => setDropdown(!dropdown);

 return (
    <div className="dropdown">
        <button onClick={toggleOpen}>
          Dropdown
        </button>
        <div
          className={`dropdown-menu ${dropdown ? 'show' : ''}`}
          aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
          >
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Delete
            </a>
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Pin to your Profile
            </a>
         </div>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the bootstrap js imported correctly

`npm install --save bootstrap`
then `import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";`

This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue need to pass **rootCloseEvent**, for example

```
<DropdownButton                          
    title="Download"
    rootCloseEvent="mousedown"
  >
    <MenuItem
      onClick={}
    >
      PDF
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem
      onClick={}
    >
      CSV
</MenuItem>
<DropdownButton/>
```