# Bootstrap 4 Javascript functionalities are not working in my react project

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

These are my import statements

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
```

I saw other questions regarding this problem and tried those solutions as well.but nothing worked for me.
I have a bootstrap navbar in my project inside `navbar` I have a `dropdownlist` which is not working(not expanding). `navbar` toggle button also not working. Given below is my `package.json` file

```
    {
  "name": "mlt",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "joi-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

I installed bootstrap by following command

```
npm i bootstrap
```

this is my `jsx` code

```
<nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light'>
                <div className='container-fluid'>
                    <Link className='navbar-brand' to='/'>
                        MLT
                    </Link>
                    <button
                        className='navbar-toggler'
                        type='button'
                        data-bs-toggle='collapse'
                        data-bs-target='#navbarNav'
                        aria-controls='navbarNav'
                        aria-expanded='false'
                        aria-label='Toggle navigation'>
                        <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarNav'>
                        <ul className='navbar-nav'>
                            <li className='nav-item'>
                                <NavLink className='nav-link' to='/stock'>
                                    Stock
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className='nav-item dropdown'>
                                <a
                                    className='nav-link dropdown-toggle'
                                    href='#'
                                    id='navbarDropdown'
                                    role='button'
                                    data-bs-toggle='dropdown'
                                    aria-expanded='false'>
                                    Create
                                </a>
                                <ul className='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='navbarDropdown'>
                                    <li>
                                        <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>
                                            Product
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>
                                            Parent Product
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a className='dropdown-item' href='#'>
                                            Brand
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li className='nav-item'>
                                <NavLink className='nav-link' to='/remove-products'>
                                    Remove Products
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className='nav-item'>
                                <NavLink className='nav-link' to='/login'>
                                    Login
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305436/bootstrap-dropdown-is-not-working-in-react

Comment: check this link hopefully it will work
https://www.techiediaries.com/react-bootstrap/#:~:text=Adding%20Bootstrap%20in%20React%20Using,by%20installing%20it%20from%20npm%20.&text=After%20installing%20the%20bootstrap%20package,your%20React%20app%20entry%20file.&text=Next%2C%20go%20to%20the%20src%2Findex.

Comment: @muhayamin `import $ from "jquery";`
`import Popper from "popper.js";` Both these statements are greyed out...means nowhere they are used

Comment: @Pulsara Sandeepa didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my project:

In my index.scss file I have:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

SCSS is basically CSS with nesting.  It's worth the extra setup to put it in your project if you have the ability too.

Also, you're not using the Bootstrap components.

instead of

```
<nav ...>
```

Try:

```
import {Navbar} from "react-bootstrap";
...
<Navbar fixed="top">
```

This itself might fix your problem.

Comment: i dont know how to implement this

Comment: I have updated my answer with something else I noticed in your code.

Comment: i installed bootstrap using `npm i bootstrap`

Comment: Yes, but you have to use the components that come with it in your JSX.  `<Navbar>` not `<nav className="navbar...">`

Comment: Install react-bootstrap with npm